Will cement board pinholes in shower wall, which are not 100% filled with waterproofing membrane, lead to moisture damage in the future?
Cement board naturally has pinholes on the surface, so when you roll on RedGard waterproofing, it does not always go into them, even with multiple coats. The most effective technique I've found is using a brush after the roller to push the RedGard into the pinholes. This is time consuming, and I've found it easy to miss pinholes.
Will the shower system be compromised, leading to future moisture damage, if the pinholes are not 100% filled?
Edit: I'm asking in reference to the shower wall, which is above the waterline. The wall will be covered with tile and grout.

Is this area above the waterline and covered with tile and grout?

Sorry, should have specified this is for the shower wall and not the base. I will update the question.

I use a 3/8 nap roller cover and glop the stuff on thick, (2 coats)  and don't have the issue.  I did if I used a thinner roller cover.

If you also properly installed waterproof paper behind the cement board (which you should do, and was traditionally always done, before people decided to rely soley on the miracle of Redguard) then I wouldn't worry too much.

I'm currently using a 3/8" nap. I'll glob it on thicker than I am now. Waterproof paper was not called for in the RedGard instructions, so I didn't use it. I'm not too worried if the membrane application is correct.
